# When I send link (my website) it shows theme name and template name how I can fix?

Tags: wordpress

is there any way to remove those.

[image]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming nor code-related topics. you can use an SEO plugin to modify those values, like Math Rank or Yoast SEO.

Answer (score 1):

It's coming from this bit in your source code:

```
<meta name="description" content="BeITService | Best WordPress theme for IT services"/>
```

Comment: How i can fix it?

Comment: Which file do i need to edit and remove this code or any way to remove this?